# Spheres collide with merry-go-round

Tags: angular-momentum, energy-conservation, rotational-dynamics, momentum, collision

Four spheres, with uniform densities $\rho_1, \rho_2, \rho_3, \rho_4$ and radii $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$, respectively, roll without slipping with constant velocities $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ along tracks that direct them towards a merry-go-round with moment of inertia $I$.

All four spheres move in perfectly straight lines.

The ride has paddles installed on it that extend straight out from its rotation axis (assume that they all have zero thickness).

All four spheres simultaneously collide, at 90-degree angles, with the paddles and each sphere contacts one paddle. Additionally, all four collisions are perfectly elastic (no energy is lost).

The problem asks for:

A. The velocities of all four spheres **after** the collisions

B. The resultant angular velocity of the merry-go-round (in ***revolutions*** per second)

The next part of the problem, a "challenge" section, is to generalise this problem to any number $n$ of spheres (given each one's radius and density), but still assuming that each sphere collides at a 90-degree angle with only one paddle.

There seems to be more unknowns than equations, especially if one had a large number of spheres. Conservation of Angular Momentum and conservation of Energy are definitely going to be used here, but ***what other equations would there be?***

I would appreciate if you could answer either or both of parts (A) and (B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are more unknowns than equations.  You do not have sufficient information to solve for the requested quantities.  Someone might be playing a prank on you!

In reality, each ball and each paddle would have a specific finite stiffness, and one could use this information along with some clever math to determine the final velocities of all the bodies.  But without making some additional assumptions about how reaction forces are divided amongst the paddles, you are stuck.

Comment: So you would need to go into things such as material science and elasticity to solve the rest?

Comment: You need additional assumptions of some kind.  Material science and elasticity was the idea that popped into my head first, and it would be a good candidate if you wanted to get a result that you could duplicate in real life.